# Getting blank surefire reports with "[WARNING] Unable to locate Test Source XRef to link to - DISABLED"

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

My pom.xml has following content

```
    <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

when I run mvn surefire-report::report I am getting following

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.18.1:report (default-cli) > [surefir
test @ TestApp >>>
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.3 is invalid, transitive depe
encies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.4 is invalid, transitive depe
encies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.testng:testng:jar:5.14.5 is invalid, transitive depe
encies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestApp
-
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TestApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @
stApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\nikhil.udgirkar\workspace\
stApp\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TestA
 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ TestApp ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.18.1:report (default-cli) < [surefir
test @ TestApp <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.18.1:report (default-cli) @ TestApp
-
[WARNING] Unable to locate Test Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.316 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-26T12:37:33+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/215M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I issued following command I am getting blank report

mvn surefire-report:report

I can get the .class files in it's respective folder

Thanks for your time

[image]

Comment: The version of testng is wrong: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22%20org.testng%22%20AND%20a%3A%22testng%22%20AND%20v%3A%225.14.3%22

Comment: @khmarbaise it is 6.8.5

Comment: But the output shows something different...or at least somewhere the dependency is written with `5.14.3`...